# Configuring HTMLPurifier to display external links as plain text

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am trying to configure HTMLPurifier to only display external links as plain text. I used DisplayLinkURI option but it display all links as a plain text. is there any configuration for that? here is my code:

```
$mySite='<a href="http://www.mysite.com/">mysite</a>';
$externalSite='<a href="http://www.external.com/">external</a>';
 require_once 'include/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
                        $Config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
                        $Config->set('AutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI', true);
                        $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($Config);
                        $mySite= $purifier->purify($mySite);
                        $externalSite=$purifier->purify($externalSite);                   
                        echo $mySite;
                        echo $externalSite;
```

The output is

```
<a>mysite</a> (http://www.mysite.com/)
<a>external</a> (http://www.external.com/)
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/">mysite</a>
<a>external</a> (http://www.external.com/)
```

Update:
I want to keep external links for images without change. I only need to convert hyperlinks to plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I succeeded to add a custom injector to HTMLPurifier, here it is:

First, Create a "**DisplayRemoteLinkURI.php"** in "**include\htmlpurifier\library\HTMLPurifier\Injector**" and write this in it

```
<?php 

class HTMLPurifier_Injector_DisplayRemoteLinkURI extends HTMLPurifier_Injector
{

    public $name = 'DisplayRemoteLinkURI';
    public $needed = array('a');

    public function handleElement(&$token) {
    }

    public function handleEnd(&$token) {
        if (isset($token->start->attr['href'])){
            $url = $token->start->attr['href'];
            if($this->is_remote($url)){
                unset($token->start->attr['href']);
                $token = array($token, new HTMLPurifier_Token_Text(" ($url)"));
            }
        } else {
            // nothing to display
        }
    }

    public function is_remote($path){
        $urlvar = parse_url($path);
        $remote_schemes = array("mailto");
        $local_schemes = array("javascript");

        if(in_array($urlvar["scheme"],$remote_schemes)){
             return true;
        }else if(in_array($urlvar["scheme"],$local_schemes)){
             return false;
        }else{
             if(empty($urlvar["host"]) || $urlvar["host"]==$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]){
                  return false;
             }else{
                  return true;
             }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

And then create another file named "**AutoFormat.DisplayRemoteLinkURI.txt**" in "**include\htmlpurifier\library\HTMLPurifier\ConfigSchema\schema**" and add this :

```
AutoFormat.DisplayRemoteLinkURI
TYPE: bool
VERSION: 3.2.0
DEFAULT: false
--DESCRIPTION--
<p>
  This directive turns on the in-text display of Remote URIs in &lt;a&gt; tags, and disables
  those links. For example, <a href="http://example.com">example</a> becomes
example (<a>http://example.com</a>).
</p>
--# vim: et sw=4 sts=4
```

After that, Add this line

```
require 'HTMLPurifier/Injector/DisplayRemoteLinkURI.php';
```

under

```
require 'HTMLPurifier/Injector/DisplayLinkURI.php';
```

in **include\htmlpurifier\library\HTMLPurifier.includes.php**

Then, Add this line

```
require_once $__dir . '/HTMLPurifier/Injector/DisplayRemoteLinkURI.php';
```

under

```
require_once $__dir . '/HTMLPurifier/Injector/DisplayLinkURI.php';
```

in **include\htmlpurifier\library\HTMLPurifier.safe-includes.php**

After these edits, if your files are at local, run cmd.exe and go to your php directory. Then run "include/HTMLPurifier/maintenance/generate-schema-cache.php" from php.exe.

Or if you want to do this via browser, rename your .htaccess file inside "include/HTMLPurifier/maintenance/" to something else for a while, then add this line inside "generate-schema-cache.php" on the first line after the `<?php` tag;

```
php_set_env("PHP_IS_CLI",true);
```

and then run this file from browser. After you see "Saving schema.. done!", rename your **.htaccess** file back.

Then in your script, use "**AutoFormat.DisplayRemoteLinkURI**" as config, and voila!

Note that the is_remote() function inside the first file I gave here might be not so good, and I couldn't find a script that checks if a link is remote or local, so you might alter it later if you need.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your effort. I created the file, added the mentioned codes and I run the the php file from the command line. The file library/HTMLPurifier/ConfigSchema/schema.ser is created. I added AutoFormat.DisplayRemoteLinkURI  to my configuration but I got this error “Warning: Cannot set undefined directive AutoFormat.DisplayRemoteLinkURI to value in …..”. I searched for DisplayRemoteLinkURI in schema.ser but I did not find it. My files are local and I run (php  htmlpurifier/maintenance/generate-schema-cache.php). I got the message “Saving schema... done!’

Comment: Ok, I didn't make any other changes. let me look once again.

Comment: there was also a txt file I forgot to mention. I updated the code. Add the text file and rebuild the schema.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the one you're looking for

http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.DisableExternal

Comment: URI.DisableExternal will disable external resources. I need to display external hyperlinks as text while keep the internal links and images. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's an option named URI.DisableExternal and AutoFormat.Linkify. Set them both to TRUE and see what happens.

http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.DisableExternal

http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#AutoFormat.Linkify

And AutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI disables all the links. I suggest you use both the above instead of AutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI.

http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#AutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI