# Modify all links in HTML Purifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am using HTML purifier to remove all unnecessary/malicious html tags.

```
$html = 'dirty html provided by user';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'p,a[href], ... other tags);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);;
$output = $purifier->purify($html);
```

It works really nice, but I want to do a little bit more. I want to change all my `<a href='link'>...</a>` to something else like `<a href='somefunc(link)' rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> ... </a>`.

After searching for a little bit, I found the following relevant [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765982/configuring-htmlpurifier-to-display-external-links-as-plain-text), but the problem is that it requires patching a complex library (which is not really a good idea, also the solution is kind of complicated).

Reading through their [forum post](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?2,5611), it looks like there is solution for adding nofollow parameter is `$config->set("HTML.Nofollow", true);`, but I still fail to find how can modify every link.

My current solution is to parse purified html by myself and to modify a link, but I think that there is a way to do this through `HTML Purifier`.

Comment: You can find some information about how to use HTML Purifier to alter HTML here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638640/html-purifier-removing-an-element-conditionally-based-on-its-attributes - I'm not posting this as an answer because it does the opposite you want :) but you can find some interesting information about attribute handling in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I found partial solution on [one of the links on the forum](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,6182,6182#msg-6182).

This is what I need to do:

```
$config->set('HTML.Nofollow', true);
$config->set('HTML.TargetBlank', true);
```

So the full thing looks like this:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Nofollow', true);
$config->set('HTML.TargetBlank', true);
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a,b,strong,i,em,u');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

Answer (score 2):

Htmlpurifier offers an API for URL mangling.

See http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-uri-filter.html

Basically you create a filter class like

```
class HTMLPurifier_URIFilter_MyPostFilter extends HTMLPurifier_URIFilter
{
    public $name = 'MyPostFilter';
    public $post = true;
    public function prepare($config) {}
    public function filter(&$uri, $config, $context) {
        // ... extra code here
    }
}
```

You do your magic in the filter function. Have a look in the documentation for the semantics of the url object that gets passed.

You can then activate the filter with

```
$uri = $config->getDefinition('URI');
$uri->addFilter(new HTMLPurifier_URIFilter_MyPostFilter(), $config);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace()`. The regex would be:

```
/<a href='(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])'>([a-zA-Z0-9\s._\-]*)<\/a>/
```

So the function would be:

```
$pattern = "/<a href='(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])'>([a-zA-Z0-9\s._\-]*)<\/a>/";
$replacement = "<a href='$1' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>$2</a>";
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $html);
```

Also if you want to do something with the url, the replacement string would be:

```
$replacement = "<a href='".somefunction("$1")."' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>$2</a>";
```

[The regex explain and examples.](http://regex101.com/r/mJ8qM9)

**Edit:** Adding attributes to links in HTML Purifier:

```
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('a', 'target', 'Enum#_blank,_self,_target,_top');
```

[More about adding attributes in HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html#addAttribute)

Comment: Thanks, but this is similar to what I am currently doing. I was looking if there is a way to do this in HTMLPurifier

Comment: Added example of adding attributes in HTML Purifier also, tho.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Also this is not doing what I want, this is a nice starting point.